# why is there a big gap between text?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I don't understand why there is so much vertical space between `Status:` and `CLOSED`. This problem only occurs when on smaller screens (due to them being side by side on desktop).

The code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm">
                <h1 class="status">Status:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6 text-sm-left">
                <span class="closed">closed</span>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

```
.closed {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #2eb82e;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #29a329;
}
.status {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```
   @media (min-width: 2561px) {
     .container {
         margin-top: 20vh;
     }
     .status {
       font-size: 120px;
     }
     .closed {
       font-size: 120px;
       margin-left: 80px;
     }
   }
/**
 * XL desktops
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 2560px){
  .status {
    font-size: 90px;
  }
  .closed {
    font-size: 90px;
  }
  .container {
      margin-top: 18vh;
      margin-left: 20%
  }
}

/**
 * LG laptops
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .closed {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
  .status {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}


/**
 * MD Tablet
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .closed {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .status {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

/**
 * SM biggerphone
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .closed {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .status {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

/**
 * XS Small phone
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 575px){

 .status {
   font-size: 50px;
 }
 .closed {
   font-size: 55px;
   line-height: normal;
 }
 .container {
   margin-top: 5vh;
 }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

> EDIT:
>   I think the padding comes from one of the `col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6` classes. when I inspect the div the `.closed` and `.status` elements do not have this padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "margin: 0" property can fix the problem. it is because bootstrap has a desault margin for titles itself.

```css
.closed {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #2eb82e;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #29a329;
  margin: 0;
}
.status {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 2561px) {
     .container {
         margin-top: 20vh;
     }
     .status {
       font-size: 120px;
     }
     .closed {
       font-size: 120px;
       margin-left: 80px;
     }
   }
/**
 * XL desktops
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 2560px){
  .status {
    font-size: 90px;
  }
  .closed {
    font-size: 90px;
  }
  .container {
      margin-top: 18vh;
      margin-left: 20%
  }
}

/**
 * LG laptops
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .closed {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
  .status {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}


/**
 * MD Tablet
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .closed {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .status {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

/**
 * SM biggerphone
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .closed {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .status {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

/**
 * XS Small phone
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 575px){

 .status {
   font-size: 50px;
 }
 .closed {
   font-size: 55px;
   line-height: normal;
 }
 .container {
   margin-top: 5vh;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm">
                <h1 class="status">Status:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6 text-sm-left">
                <span class="closed">closed</span>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: 575px){
 .status {
   font-size: 50px;
   line-height: .8; 
 }
 .closed {
   font-size: 55px;
   line-height: .8;
 }
 .container {
   margin-top: 5vh;
 }
}
```

As I understand, you had a problem when you use text 
with a big size. so you can play with line-height. above you can see an example.
https://jsfiddle.net/csscoder/xmgskj0w/6/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the vertical distance between the two texts should be smaller?.The green box around `Status:` means there is padding on that element, if you add `padding-bottom: 0` The two text will be closer. Also H1 by default has margin bottom on it as well so if you give it a `margin-bottom: 0` it will also help reduce the space.

Comment: tried both, nothing reduced the space. Yes it is the vertical distance between `Status:` I want reduced

Comment: From the image above your `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm">` has some padding. If you give it a add a class like `<div class="status col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm">` and apply styling `.status{padding: 0}` it should remove the padding. 

You may also have some padding/margin on your `closed` element

Comment: Just to clarify I'm saying to add `status` class so you can override the bootstrap styling on that div. If my answer helps don't forget to upvote or select it as the answer.

Comment: There must be something that I'm missing is your code hosted somewhere like github?

Comment: Can make a codepen link. https://codepen.io/andve04/full/oNXwbrL  if you try to minimize the page slowly you can see the content jump and space in the end

Comment: hmm. on my localhost there is a big gap, but when I copy it into codepen it disappear?

Comment: yeah I'm noticing that in the codepen there is no padding or margin between the two elements. But in the image you posted above it's there because we see the green. Also in your image it says `div.container1` but that is not present in the code you provided

Comment: Container1 was just to add color to easly SEE the div Before, no longer in USE

Comment: When i search for «padding» I dont get any relevant finds